# Getting all usersinfos from Windows server's Active Directory via LDAP (ldap3 Python)

Tags: python, ldap, windows-server, ldap3, windows-server-2022

I would like to fetch every users infos (firstname, lastname, email) from a Windows Server's Active Directory.
So I'm using ldap3 (python) and successed connected to the server (using HyperV Windows Server 2022) with my admin logs:

```
from ldap3 import Server, Connection, ALL, NTLM, SAFE_SYNC
server = Server('ldap://172.28.63.240', get_info=ALL)
conn = Connection(server, user="TESTJER\Administrator", 
password="my_admin_password",client_strategy=SAFE_SYNC, auto_bind=True)

status, result, response, _ = conn.search('OU=Users2,DC=testjer,DC=local', 
'(givenName=*)')
print(response)
```

But I will need to connect to multiple differents servers in the future so I think I will not able (and it's maybe a bad idea) to have an admin account to see everything on every client's servers?

So I tried to initialize a Instance by installing a AD LDS and choosing instance name, Description, ports, etc...

But I'm not able to connect with python by specify the port, I can connect if I don't put the port so that means the Instance is useless.

> ldap3.core.exceptions.LDAPBindError: automatic bind not successful - **invalidCredentials**

Do my needs make that I have to install an instance with a usage to only see Users infos and nothing else? How?

What I did to create the instance:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Here, I was not sure at all on what to write here, but I guess OU=Users2 means fetching only the Users2. This is what I want cause my users are :

[image]

And here I saw that I have anyway to pu an users so I have no choice I put actually my Administrator account but in the future every clients will have to create an account for me:

[image]

And finaly I guess I had to choose "MS-User.LDF" here:
[image]

```
from ldap3 import Server, Connection, ALL, NTLM, SAFE_SYNC
server = Server('ldap://172.28.63.240', port=50001, get_info=ALL)
conn = Connection(server, user="TESTJER\Administrator", 
password="my_admin_password",client_strategy=SAFE_SYNC, auto_bind=True)

status, result, response, _ = conn.search('OU=Users2,DC=testjer,DC=local', 
'(givenName=*)')
print(response)
```

Answer (score 0):

`ldap3.Connection.search()` returns max 1000 entries by default for AD

You want to use `ldap3.Connection.extend.standard.paged_search()` for AD instead. The search parameters are basically the same as a regular search, but this function will give you all of the ldap entries as a returned generator object. In order to then get all of the results in a parsable format, just list cast it or for loop through it!

Something like `ad_entries = list(ldap_conn.extend.standard.paged_search())`